# How to call exe with multiple arguments from VB.Net Source?

Tags: vb.net

How to call `exe` with multiple arguments from `VB.Net` Source. Now, I can call `exe` file with  `mmyProcess.StartInfo.FileName  ="....exe"` and pass parameters with `myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments` but i can't pass multiple parameters with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple arguments to `myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments` by separating them with a space like this:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "first second third"
```

If you need spaces, use this:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("""{0}"" ""{1}"" ""{2}""", first, second, third)
```